# Wordpress same post multiple displays

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm slightly stuck on a solution to a problem in Wordpress. I have a site where it lists 'clients' as a custom post type. These clients can either be an Author, a Speaker or Both. When adding a client I've set 2 text boxes for biographies - so it can accept separate bio information for Speaker and Author (rather than creating 2 separate clients with matching names, headshots etc). Author and Speaker have been set as custom taxonomies.

On the front end, I've created a couple of list pages, one that lists all Authors, the other than lists all Speakers. This is all fine so far.

What I haven't solved on the front end is how to display the clients Speaker info if they are accessed via SiteMenu>Clients>Speakers>JoeBloggs and conversely their Author info via SiteMenu>Clients>Authors>JoeBloggs.

I guess I would need to capture the previous URL that the visitor is coming from, check if they are looking for a speaker or author, and then display the relevant client info. Or is there an easier way?

Comment: What are you using get_posts() or wp_query() in these pages?

Comment: Using wp_query() on the lists pages.

Comment: Maybe it would be easiest to pass a variable to the permalink on each page, such as `clients-name?profile=author` and then catch it on the clients page?

Comment: Yes, i will go with the same suggestion that you should distinguish the pages with some parameter. Else you have to do the same thing with session.